# What is skew value in Mongo DB Database replication?

Tags: server, monitor, database, aws, mongodb

I have just started the three MongoDB replica servers.

- I do not understand what is this screw value what it should be on which server?
- Which values should I monitor
- I have taken 2 screenshots shown below for Primary Mongo DB Server, Secondary Mongo DB Server & Arbiter Mongo DB Server respectively.

  ```
             ## Primary Mongo DB Server --- Location : Singapore ##
  ```

  [image]

  ```
         ## Secondary Mongo DB Server --- Location : North Virginia ##
  ```

  [image]

  ```
             ## Arbiter Mongo DB Server --- Location : Singapore ##
  ```

  [image]

As far as I understand they are in sync very well and all of them are AWS Instances.

1. I need to know how and what should I monitor?
2. What kind of maintenance activities should I do & how?

Please feel free to let me know if you need any further info. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "skew" column represents how skewed each host perceives the others' system clocks to be relative to its own.

If you're running a version 2.0 or later of MongoDB, these numbers are just for your information and not something to worry about — the servers are aware of the skew and will compensate for it.  (See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3132 for gory details.)